# Unity Не могу закинуть скрипт c# в поле, в инспекторе

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть поле в инспекторе для типа ManagerBase(класс унаследованный от ScriptableObject). Хочу закинуть скрипт с классом, который унаследован от ManagerBase, но не получается. Даже если изменить тип поля на SctiptableObject, то ничего не измениться. Скорее всего я делаю, это неправильно, поэтому буду рад вашим исправлениям. 
Код самого ManagerBase(который кстати тоже не добавляется)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Manager
{
    public class ManagerBase : ScriptableObject { }
}
```

Код одного из скриптов, унаследованных от ManagerBase:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using Interfaces;

namespace Manager
{
    public class ManagerUpdate : ManagerBase, IAwake
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Список Update
        /// </summary>
        private List<ITick> ticks = new List<ITick>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Список FixedUpdate
        /// </summary>
        private List<IFixedTick> fixedTicks = new List<IFixedTick>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Список Late Update
        /// </summary>
        private List<ILateTick> lateTicks = new List<ILateTick>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление нового елемента в списки tick, fixedTicks, lateTicks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updateble">Елемент использующий Tick(), FixedTick или LateTick</param>
        public static void AddTo(object updateble)
        {
            //Получение ManagerUpdate из Toolbox
            var mngUpdate = Toolbox.Toolbox.Get<ManagerUpdate>();

            if (updateble is ITick)
                mngUpdate.ticks.Add(updateble as ITick);

            if (updateble is IFixedTick)
                mngUpdate.fixedTicks.Add(updateble as IFixedTick);

            if (updateble is ILateTick)
                mngUpdate.lateTicks.Add(updateble as ILateTick);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Удаление нового елемента в списки tick, fixedTicks, lateTicks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updateble">Елемент использующий Tick(), FixedTick или LateTick</param>
        public static void Remove(object updateble)
        {
            var mngUpdate = Toolbox.Toolbox.Get<ManagerUpdate>();

            if (updateble is ITick)
                mngUpdate.ticks.Remove(updateble as ITick);

            if (updateble is IFixedTick)
                mngUpdate.fixedTicks.Remove(updateble as IFixedTick);

            if (updateble is ILateTick)
                mngUpdate.lateTicks.Remove(updateble as ILateTick);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Замена Update
        /// </summary>
        public void Tick()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < ticks.Count; ++i) ticks[i].Tick();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Замена FixedUpdate
        /// </summary>
        public void FixedTick()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < fixedTicks.Count; ++i) fixedTicks[i].FixedTick();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Замена FixedUpdate
        /// </summary>
        public void LateTick()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < lateTicks.Count; ++i) lateTicks[i].LateTick();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление в [SETUP] компонента ManagerUpdateComponent
        /// </summary>
        public void OnAwake()
        {
            GameObject.Find("[SETUP]").AddComponent<ManagerUpdateComponent>().Setup(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Код скрипта, который заменяет вид компонента в инспекторе:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

using Manager;

namespace ComponentEditor {

    /// <summary>
    /// Editor-класс для елемента Starter.Starter
    /// </summary>
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Starter.Starter))]
    [CanEditMultipleObjects]
    public class StarterEditor : Editor
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Изменяемый Компонент
        /// </summary>
        private Starter.Starter starter;

        /// <summary>
        /// Получение компонента при активации
        /// </summary>
        public void OnEnable()
        {
            starter = (Starter.Starter)target;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Изменение вида компонента
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            //Вывод инфы о размерах списка
            EditorGUILayout.IntField("Кол-во менеджеров", starter.managers.Count);
            EditorGUILayout.IntField("Размер", starter.managers.Capacity);

            //Проверка на наличие менеджеров в списке
            if (starter.managers.Count == 0) EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Нет елементов в списке!");

            //Перебеор всех менеджеров
            for (var index = 0; index < starter.managers.Count; ++index)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

                //Вывод пменеджера
                starter.managers[index] = (ManagerBase)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Менеджер " + index.ToString(), starter.managers[index], typeof(ManagerBase), false);
                if (GUILayout.Button("-")) starter.managers.RemoveAt(index); //Кнопка для удаления менеджера

                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }

            //Кнопка для добавления менеджера
            if (GUILayout.Button("+")) starter.managers.Add(new ManagerBase());

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if (GUILayout.Button("Очистить место")) starter.managers.TrimExcess();//Очистка лишнего места
            if (GUILayout.Button("Удалить всё")) starter.managers.Clear();//Удаление всех менеджеров

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            if (GUI.changed) SetObjectDirty(starter.gameObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Если поле измененно, то делать сцену "грязной"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">GameObject компонента</param>
        private void SetObjectDirty(GameObject obj)
        {
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(obj);
            EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(obj.scene);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код покажите...

Comment: Код скриптов добавил

Comment: А SciptableObject где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Unity есть два базовых класса - `MonoBehaiviour`, который является частью "компонентой" системы и чьи наследники единственные способны добавляться в виде компонентов на игровые объекты.
И класс `ScriptableObject`, который представляет собой систему ассетов и служит для создание файлов с расширением .asset.

Другими словами: на игровой объект в качестве компонента вы можете добавить только наследника `MonoBehaiviour`. А уже в поле этого компонента можно поместить ссылку на созданный ассет типа-наследника `ScriptableObject`.

Чтобы создать экземпляр класса-наследника `ScriptableObject` вам нужно использовать [специальный атрибут `CreateAssetMenu`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html), который добавит в меню пункт для создания объекта в папке ассетов.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName= "ManagerUpdate", menuName = "Managers/ManagerUpdate ")]
public class ManagerUpdate : ManagerBase, IAwake
{
}
```

Код такого вида позволит вам создать экземпляр вашего класса, если вы нажмёте правой кнопкой внутри файловой иерархии и пройдете по пути `Create=>Managers` где нажмёте `ManagerUpdate`

После чего созданный файл-asset можно будет поместить в одно из полей игрового объекта.

Comment: То-есть мне нужно в те поля помещать asset-файл?

Comment: @ДимаСурок, да, верно

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Можно ещё один вопрос? У меня есть поле для GameObject, но не получается засунуть туда обычный объект.

Comment: @ДимаСурок, не совсем понимаю как это возможно) туда только объекты со сцены переместить можно, либо префабы из файлов

Comment: Так я и перемещаю объект со сцены, а вот префабы получается